# DeleteRecursively in Word VBA only deleting first item in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ms-word, comments

I have a large VBA script, written in Word, which extracts all comments from a Word document and writes them to an Excel spreadsheet. Additionally, it identifies (according to date, user choice and comment resolution status) comments which can be deleted. I store the comment index in an array, and then work through the array to delete each comment (excerpt provided below, full code at the end):

```
    For DeleteCommentIndex = LBound(DeleteItems) To UBound(DeleteItems)

        StatusBar = "Deleting comment #" & DeleteCommentIndex + 1 & " of " & UBound(DeleteItems) + 1 _
            & ", comment index #" & DeleteItems(DeleteCommentIndex)
        MsgBox DeleteCommentIndex & "-" & DeleteItems(DeleteCommentIndex)
        ActiveDocument.Comments(DeleteItems(DeleteCommentIndex)).DeleteRecursively

    Next DeleteCommentIndex
```

In the code the *DeleteItems* array is established as:

```
Dim DeleteItems() as Integer
```

...and then REDIM'd as I find another comment index to add to the list.

When the macro completes, I can see that the document has a number of Undo options which equate to the number of comments which have been deleted:
[screencap of Word undo list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiU8I.png) .
However, when I check the comments, only the first comment ever actually gets deleted. My message box (as per the code) shows the correct array position, and the correct value within the array. Also, I can display a message box which will show the correct comment text.
When I rerun the macro immediately afterwards, the *next* array item then gets deleted. It's like the DeleteRecursively only fires once for the first array item per For - Next loop.

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks in advance. (full code below)

```
Sub exportComments()
' Exports comments from a MS Word document to Excel and associates them with the text and page number
' Thanks to Graham Mayor, http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/export-word-review-comments-in-excel/54818c46-b7d2-416c-a4e3-3131ab68809c
' and Wade Tai, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140225(v=office.10).aspx
' Need to set a VBA reference to "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library"


Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim i, HeadingRow, WriteRow, WriteCommentRow, WriteDeletedRow, CelltoFormat, ReviewerCellToFormat As Integer
Dim ReviewWriteRow, SheetToFormat, IndexValue, CountDeleteItems As Integer
Dim CellColour, FontColour As Integer, IsBold As Boolean
Dim RowIsAged As Boolean
Dim objPara As Paragraph
Dim objComment As Comment
Dim strSection, WriteToSheet As String
Dim strTemp
Dim myRange As Range
Dim lngIndex As Long
Dim lastRow, DoYouWantToDelete As Integer
Dim DeleteDate As String
Dim CommentRow(9) As Variant 'Create an array to hold the comment information
Dim DeleteItems() As Integer

'These three values affect the formatting of the header row
CellColour = 11
FontColour = 2
IsBold = True

CelltoFormat = 1
ReviewerCellToFormat = 1
RowIsAged = False
IndexValue = 1
CountDeleteItems = -1

If ActiveDocument.Comments.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The document contains no comments"
    Exit Sub
End If

' First check to see if the user wants to delete old comments
' Firstly, get the date from which comments should be deleted

DoYouWantToDelete = MsgBox("Do you wish to delete aged comments from this document?", _
                    vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Delete aged comments?")

If DoYouWantToDelete = vbYes Then
    DeleteDate = InputBox("Please enter a date (comments older than this date will be removed)" & _
                    vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Use the format dd/mm/yy", "Deleting old comments", "Please enter a date in format dd/mm/YYYY")
    
    If IsDate(DeleteDate) Then
        DeleteDate = CDate(DeleteDate)
    Else
        MsgBox "Wrong date format" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please rerun the macro with a correct date format"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
Else
    MsgBox "No comments will be deleted"
End If

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add 'create a new workbook
xlWB.Sheets.Add After:=xlWB.Worksheets(1)
xlApp.Sheets(1).Name = "Comments"
xlApp.Sheets(2).Name = "Reviewers"

If DoYouWantToDelete = vbYes Then 'If the user wants to delete comments, create a sheet to capture the info
    xlWB.Sheets.Add After:=xlWB.Worksheets(2)
    xlApp.Sheets(3).Name = "DeletedComments"
End If

xlApp.Worksheets("Comments").Activate

With xlWB.Worksheets(1)
' Create Heading
    HeadingRow = 1
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 1).Formula = "Comment"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 2).Formula = "Page"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 3).Formula = "Section"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 4).Formula = "Text"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 5).Formula = "Original Comment"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 6).Formula = "Raised by"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 7).Formula = "Date Raised"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 8).Formula = "Replies"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 9).Formula = "Last Update"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 10).Formula = "Status"
    
    xlWB.Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Initial"
    xlWB.Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Name"
    
    For CelltoFormat = 1 To 10 '10 columns, format each one the same
        .Cells(HeadingRow, CelltoFormat).Interior.ColorIndex = CellColour
        .Cells(HeadingRow, CelltoFormat).Font.ColorIndex = FontColour
        .Cells(HeadingRow, CelltoFormat).Font.Bold = IsBold
    Next CelltoFormat
    
'Copy this format to the Deleted Comments tab (if we have one)
    If DoYouWantToDelete = vbYes Then
        xlWB.Worksheets("Comments").UsedRange.Copy
        xlWB.Worksheets("DeletedComments").Select
        xlWB.Worksheets("DeletedComments").Range("A1").Select
        xlWB.Worksheets("DeletedComments").Paste
    End If
  
    WriteCommentRow = 1
    WriteDeletedRow = 1
    ReviewerWriteRow = 2
    
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments.Count 'For every comment in the document
        xlApp.StatusBar = "Processing comment " & i & " of " & ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
            
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Scope
        
        CommentRow(0) = IndexValue 'Write an index number
        CommentRow(1) = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Reference.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) 'Write the page number
        CommentRow(2) = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Scope.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString 'Write the section number
        CommentRow(3) = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Scope.FormattedText 'Write the commented text
        CommentRow(4) = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Range 'Write the comment itself
        CommentRow(5) = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Initial 'Write the initials of who raised the comment
                      
        With xlWB.Worksheets(2) 'Write the reviewer and their initials to the Reviewer sheet
            .Cells(ReviewerWriteRow, 1).Value = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Initial
            .Cells(ReviewerWriteRow, 2).Value = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Author
        End With
        
        ReviewerWriteRow = ReviewerWriteRow + 1
        
        CommentRow(6) = Format(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Date, "MM/dd/yyyy") 'Write teh date the comment was raised
        
        If ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies.Count > 0 Then 'Go though all the replies add put them in the next field
           For lngIndex = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies.Count
              
              
              CommentRow(7) = CommentRow(7) & ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies(lngIndex).Range.Text _
              & " [" & ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies(lngIndex).Initial & "] " _
              & " [" & Format(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies(lngIndex).Date, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "] " _
              & vbNewLine & vbNewLine 'Add initials of who made the replay, and the date is was made
                           
              'CommentRow(8) = Format(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies(lngIndex).Date, "mmddyyyy")
              CommentRow(8) = CDate(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies(lngIndex).Date)
                            
              If DoYouWantToDelete = vbYes Then
                If CDate(CommentRow(8)) <= CDate(DeleteDate) Then
                      RowIsAged = True
                Else
                      RowIsAged = False
                End If
              End If
                
              With xlWB.Worksheets(2)
                .Cells(ReviewerWriteRow, 1).Value = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies(lngIndex).Initial
                .Cells(ReviewerWriteRow, 2).Value = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies(lngIndex).Author
              End With
              ReviewerWriteRow = ReviewerWriteRow + 1
                         
           Next lngIndex
        Else 'There are no replies, so we need to set the last updated field to be the same date the comment was raised
            CommentRow(8) = Format(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Date, "MM/dd/yyyy")
        End If
        
        If ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Done Then 'Get the comment status (open or resolved)
            CommentRow(9) = "Resolved"
        Else
            CommentRow(9) = "Open"
        End If
        
        'Now write the comment info to either the main comments tab, or the deleted comments tab
        If CommentRow(9) = "Resolved" And RowIsAged And DoYouWantToDelete = vbYes Then
            CountDeleteItems = CountDeleteItems + 1
            ReDim Preserve DeleteItems(CountDeleteItems) 'Resize our tracking array
            WriteToSheet = "DeletedComments"
            WriteDeletedRow = WriteDeletedRow + 1 'This is to track which row in our deleted comments sheet is next
            WriteRow = WriteDeletedRow
            DeleteItems(CountDeleteItems) = i 'Keep a note of which comments are to be deleted

        Else
            WriteToSheet = "Comments"
            WriteCommentRow = WriteCommentRow + 1 'This is to track which row in our standard comments sheet is next
            WriteRow = WriteCommentRow
        End If
        
        If ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies.Count <> 0 Then
          i = i + ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Replies.Count 'Jump the counter forward to account for the replies
        End If
        
        For ArrayIndex = 0 To 9 'Now write each element of the array to the relevant row in the right tab
           xlWB.Worksheets(WriteToSheet).Cells(WriteRow, ArrayIndex + 1).Value = CommentRow(ArrayIndex)
        Next ArrayIndex
        
        IndexValue = IndexValue + 1
        
        Erase CommentRow() 'Clear the array ready for the next set of comments
        
    Next i
    
    xlApp.StatusBar = "Completed processing of " & ActiveDocument.Comments.Count & " comments"
    
    'Format the worksheets
    If DoYouWantToDelete = vbYes Then
        For SheetToFormat = 1 To 3 Step 2
          With xlWB.Worksheets(SheetToFormat)
            .Columns("A:J").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
            .Columns("A:J").Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
            .Columns("A:J").Cells.WrapText = True
            .Columns("D:E").ColumnWidth = 50
            .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 12
            .Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 50
            .Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 12
            .Columns("I").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            .UsedRange.EntireRow.AutoFit
            'Add an autofilter to all the columns and freeze the top row
            .Columns("A:J").Autofilter
            xlApp.Cells(2, 1).Select
            xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
          End With
        Next SheetToFormat
    Else
        With xlWB.Worksheets(1)
            .Columns("A:J").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
            .Columns("A:J").Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
            .Columns("A:J").Cells.WrapText = True
            .Columns("D:E").ColumnWidth = 50
            .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 12
            .Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 50
            .Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 12
            .Columns("I").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            .UsedRange.EntireRow.AutoFit
            'Add an autofilter to all the columns and freeze the top row
            .Columns("A:J").Autofilter
            xlApp.Cells(2, 1).Select
            xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
          End With
    End If

    'Remove duplicates in the Reviewers worksheet and format it
    With xlWB.Worksheets(2)
    
        .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 30
    
        For ReviewerCellToFormat = 1 To 2
            .Cells(HeadingRow, ReviewerCellToFormat).Interior.ColorIndex = CellColour
            .Cells(HeadingRow, ReviewerCellToFormat).Font.ColorIndex = FontColour
            .Cells(HeadingRow, ReviewerCellToFormat).Font.Bold = IsBold
        Next ReviewerCellToFormat
            
        'Remove duplicates
        lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        .Range("A1:B" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
        
        'Sort the Reviewer names in alphabetical order
        lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count 'We need to recheck this as the duplicates will have been removed
        .Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Sort key1:=.Range("A2:A" & lastRow), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End With

End With

'Delete the comments before tidying up, setting focus and final status message
xlWB.Worksheets("Comments").Activate
Word.Application.Activate
 
If DoYouWantToDelete = vbYes Then
    'Go ahead and delete the comments
    
    MsgBox "There are " & UBound(DeleteItems) + 1 & " comments to delete." & _
        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Are you sure you wish delete these?"
        
    For DeleteCommentIndex = LBound(DeleteItems) To UBound(DeleteItems)
    
        StatusBar = "Deleting comment #" & DeleteCommentIndex + 1 & " of " & UBound(DeleteItems) + 1 _
            & ", comment index #" & DeleteItems(DeleteCommentIndex)
        MsgBox DeleteCommentIndex & "-" & DeleteItems(DeleteCommentIndex)
        ActiveDocument.Comments(DeleteItems(DeleteCommentIndex)).DeleteRecursively
        
    Next DeleteCommentIndex

End If

MsgBox ("Comment processing is complete. In total, " & ActiveDocument.Comments.Count & " comments were processed." & vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & "We recommend you save the spreadsheet with a data and time stamp in the title.")

Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try running the loop backwards when you are deleting item from a collection.

Comment: So in other words, from Ubound(DeleteItems) to LBound(DeleteItems)?

Comment: `For DeleteCommentIndex = Ubound(DeleteItems) to LBound(DeleteItems) Step -1` @StuartL

Comment: Thankyou very much, that seems to have done the trick! Any explanation as to why it works going backwards through the array, but not forwards?

Comment: Its a common mistake ppl make when they are deleting item from a collection in a loop. When you delete an item (say the 2nd item) from a collection, the rest of the items behind it will move its index up by 1 but your loop is looping based on the original index. By deleting from the back, you dont mess the index up. I wont post an answer for this since this can be considered a duplicate question (there are manyyyy questions asked for this issue) @StuartL

Comment: Note that this applies when you delete item from a collection generally, its not an issue with Comment collection specifically

Comment: Thankyou for that, and I understand if I were deleting things out of the array. But I'm only using the array as a reference to identify a specific comment (given by `DeleteItems(DeleteCommentIndex)` ) . I didn't think I was actually affecting the contents of the array?

Comment: You are affecting the `ActiveDocument.Comments` collection and your array provides the index which will be all wrong the moment you delete 1 comment from the collection. @StuartL

Comment: Ahhhhh! I get it now. Thankyou very much for your help and explanations. I don't think I can upvote your comments, but thankyou anyway.

Comment: A couple things thats not related to your question: 1) `Dim strSection, WriteToSheet As String` means `strSection` is declared as `Variant`, you need to implicitly declare each variable type. E.g. `Dim strSection As String, WriteToSheet As String`. This applies to all your variable declaration. 2) For those `Integer` variable, you can change it to `Long`, `Integer` is pretty much useless in modern days VBA (and said to be slower as VBA will incur overhead converting integer to long internally) @StuartL

Comment: @RaymondWu Thankyou so much for your help. My first priority was getting it working, now I can optimise it. Thanks again.